# Limitar a x numero de entries cuando se exporta con DATATABLES.JS

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

que tal, alguien sabe como puedo limitar el numero de datos a exportar cuando utilizo la libreria tableTools, digamos que si utilizo 100 entries solo copiar o exportar esas 100 entries, ya que cuando copio o exporto me copia generalmente mas de 500 registros de mi db.
esta es la manera de como agrego dicha funcion del dataTable

```
$('.dataTable').dataTable({
      "bJQueryUI": 'true',
      "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
      "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
      "tableTools": {
      "sSwfPath": "./swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"}
   });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No me queda muy clara la pregunta, pero asumo que esos 100 registros son los que están visibles en la paginación actual. Entonces oSelectorOpts puede ser tu solución:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    "bJQueryUI": 'true',
    "pagingType": "full_numbers",
    "iDisplayLength": 10,
    "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
    "oTableTools": {
      "aButtons": [
        {'sExtends':'copy',
          "oSelectorOpts": { filter: 'applied', order: 'current' },
        },
        {'sExtends':'xls',
          "oSelectorOpts": { filter: 'applied', order: 'current' },
        },
        {'sExtends':'print',
          "oSelectorOpts": { filter: 'applied', order: 'current' },
        }
      ]
    },
});
});
```

Comment: Justo en el clavo! Gracias @vmartinetti